# ArrayBuffer not persisting values outside loop in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert rdd to 2-D array. I am using below code for this -

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var temp=new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[_>:Double]]
    f.foreach(x=> {
    temp:+= ArrayBuffer(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4))
    println(temp)
})
println(temp)
```

Here f is my rdd. println statement inside loop is working correctly. But when the outside println executes, it does not show anything. Can someone please explain why this is happening ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that others can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you haven't provide `f` implementation I am guessing it as `RDD[Array]`.

`RDD` are distributed in nature. When we apply a function such as `map`, `foreach`, `reduce` etc. on an `RDD` they are executed in distributed manner i.e. since `RDD` is already distributed the `foreach` function was also carried out in distributed manner on `executor` nodes. And since `temp`  is pointing to the `ArrayBuffer` created on the `driver` node, the distribute execution couldn't update the `ArrayBuffer` pointed by `temp`.

The correct solution would be to `collect` `f` before applying `foreach` function as

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var temp=new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[_>:Double]]

f.collect.foreach(x=> {
  temp += ArrayBuffer(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4))
  println(temp)
})
println(temp)
```

You should be getting expected output.